# Error when compiling a .bas file using FreeBASIC: Expected End-of-Line, found '['

Tags: compiling, freebasic

I tried making a simple code to get into .bas based coding. I was using FreeBASIC code compiler to create my codes. I tried making a simple code that will bring out any text into the terminal.

`read.bas` file:

```
[code]
print "read"
[/code]
```

and then I compiled it using

```
$ fbc -lang qb read.bas
```

what I got was this.

```
read.bas(1) error 3: Expected End-of-Line, found '['
[code]
^
read.bas(3) error 3: Expected End-of-Line, found '['
[/code]
^
```

I am new to Ubuntu but I have messed around with it a bit. Please help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `[code]` and `[/code]` were tags used to identified the code content but are NOT part of the code you need to compile using `fbc`:

Try the following `read.bas`:

```
print "read"
```

It will work as expected:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/fbc -lang qb ./read.bas
$ ./read
read
$
```